# Blazor -valid antiforgery token was not provided with the request. Add an antiforgery token, or disable antiforgery validation for this endpoint

Tags: .net-core, blazor, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I created a Microsoft Teams app using Razor components and have configured the following it, but still receive an antiforgery token error.
In program.cs
`app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents()
.AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();`
I have also added the tag   to my .razor page.

Comment: Make sure that the `app.UseAntiforgery()` comes after the `app.useRouting()`. Can you provide a bit more information? When do you encounter the error? What does the invoking and the target components look like? What version of .NET are you using? 

There's not a lot of information that you've provided, making it difficult to pinpoint what's going wrong. Also, are you 100% sure that the URL's match up? Check the path, App Base/root and case sensitivity as well.

For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: It's discussed here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/50612